# convert cer to csr using openssl or keytool

Tags: openssl, keytool

Is it possible to generate a csr file from cer file using openssl or keytool? I can see commands to convert the other way.
Or, is it possible to generate a public pem file from the cer file?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a CSR from a certificate using OpenSSL as follows:

```
openssl x509 -x509toreq -signkey ./server.key -in ./server.pem -out server.csr
```

will create a certificate request from the certificate and private key.  Note that you *must* have the private key available for this to work as the csr is signed by the private key in order to provide proof of possession.

You can generate a `.pem` from a `.cer` in one of two ways:

1. If the file is in DER format (a binary format) you can use: `openssl x509 -inform DER in server.cer -out server.pem`.
2. If the file is in PEM format (a base64 text format) you can simply rename it from `.cer` to `.pem`.  Remember the `cer` is only a file extension and doesn't really define the content of the file.

Comment: what is server.key here ?

Comment: It's exactly what it says under `-signkey` in the [man page for openssl x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html) - it's the private key of the certificate.  You must have a private key in order to sign the CSR.

Comment: Tried openssl x509 -inform DER -in server.cer -out server.pem. Gave error as:-          unable to load certificate
15040:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1315:
15040:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:379:Type=X509

Comment: Then your file is already in PEM format and doesn't need converting.  That's option 2 in my answer.  Look at the contents of the file - if it's a mess, it's DER; but if it's a tidy block of base64 characters with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` delimiters then it's a PEM file.